# Exclude javascript from specific page

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

I have a javascript that is running only on my website.com/index.php, excluding all the links like website.com/products/ or website.com/services/. Problem is, when I search for something, it takes me to website.com/search?=somethingsomething and the javascript that was supposed to run only on my homepage is happening there too.

How can I exclude the javascript from running in all the other root / pages?

I am using Wordpress, should I add something to the functions.php page or directly into my .js file?

Thanks.

Comment: Does WP have all traffic go through `index.php`?  I would presume so... therefore the javascript will always run.  The quickest solution I can think of is to use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to determine if the request is for anything other than `/` and then put the javascript in an `if` block that doesn't print if there is a request uri.

Comment: This only happens with the search plugin because its in the / directory. Only if I could create a directory named search and redirect all the functions to /search/search.php instead of /search.php. Any help on doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways you could approach this

**Method 1: Only enqueue on the home page**

Place the home page only scripts in it's own file, and then check if you're on the home page before enqueuing.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'so_48392593' );

function so_48392593() {
    if( is_front_page() ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'myscript', 'myscript.js' );
    }
}
```

**Method 2: Check if it's the home page with JavaScript**

WordPress will add the `home` class to the `<body>` tag if it's the home page, so you can test against that before your script runs. This method is less foolproof as a plugin or theme could change the body classes with the `body_class` filter

```
if( jQuery( 'body' ).hasClass( 'home' ) ) {
    // Your JavaScript goes here
}
```

Answer (score -2):

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_comment.asp

Quote:

Tips and Notes
You can also use the comment tag to "hide" scripts from browsers without support for scripts (so they don't show them as plain text):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--

function displayMsg() {
    alert("Hello World!")

}
//-->
</script>
```

Note: The two forward slashes at the end of comment line (//) is the JavaScript comment symbol. This prevents JavaScript from executing the --> tag.

Comment: thats not what he is asking